# Inserting values from a file to a function using c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to take numbers from a file that each line has a number.

```
3
7
8
5
2
1
```

and insert the integers from a file to a function within my code called insert().

This is what I have:

```
   int main()
    {   ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open("numbers.txt");
        while(!myfile == EOF)
        {
            myfile.getline(myfile,1000000);
            insert(myfile);
        }
        myfile.close();


display();
return 0;
}
```

I get this error aggregate 'std::ifstream myfile' has incomplete type and cannot be defined.

Comment: You need to add `#include <fstream>  using namespace std;` at the beggining of the file.

Comment: When reading a file is the numbers a string or an integers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

at the beggining of the file.

EDIT: also, you are calling `insert(myfile);` where `myfile` is of type `ìfstream`, but your definition for `insert` is `void insert(int)`.

Comment: I added the <fstream> I get an error at the insert(myfile) which is invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int'

Answer (score 1):

`myfile.getline(myfile,1000000);`

How is this supposed to work? Let's look at the function's signature in the [DOCUMENTATION](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

`istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );`

`istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );`

Function wants You to give it a char pointer s and size of the array n and You are giving it a *ifstream myfile* and a very big random int.

Create an array for temporary storage of read lines

`char line[99];`

and then pass it to the function.

`myfile.getline(line,99);`

---

Also Your `void insert(int d)` accepts integers and Your are trying to pass fstream object to it. You can keep it like this but You'd have to convert string to int first. Try `atoi()`

Comment: I was just trying to figure out how to make it iterate through the file and insert it in the linked list while using the insert() but wasn't sure. Can I convert the string to the integers by using atoi()?

Comment: @brooklynchick Yes, of course. Extract line from file and then extract integer from it.

Comment: I made a very crucial edit to the post above. When passing char array to the function You should also pass it's size as second argument. Accept the answer if it helps ;)